# Shiny dashboard not rendering fonts propoerly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I have an issue with how stacked bar plots are rendered in a live instance hosted in ShinyDashboard. The code below is used to display a stacked bar chart in

Below is the code:

```
EducationBarPlot <- ggplot(Education.long, aes(x = Persons, y = Total, fill=Gender)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("GrandBudapest1"))+
  geom_text(aes(label=Total),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 4, color = "#ffffff") +
  labs(x="")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color="black", face = "bold", size=9),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9))+
  theme_hc()+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
  coord_flip()
EducationBarPlot
```

On Localhost, the plot looks fine. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRorq.jpg. However, on ShinyDashboard, the font looks 'squeezed'. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VO3F.jpg

Comment: Hi, please provide a reproducible example of your shiny app

Comment: Did you use the same browser for viewing both sites?

Comment: It's probably a browser issue. The fonts load differently on different browsers. Any workaround on that?